# express server redirect issues

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm building/learning a web-app with React and Express. All of the routes and redirects work but URL won't change and my props won't pass until i manually go to the URL.

For example;

After a successful login (local passport with MongoDB), it renders main page but it's empty since i don't get any data (user id or email etc..) but if enter URL manually or press home button on nav-bar, it works or if i logout it logouts but URL stays at /logout instead of /login. Example code below:

**server.js**

```
...
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash("success_msg");
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash("error_msg");
  res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
  res.locals.messages = req.flash();
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});

server.get("/index", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  const msg = {name: req.user.name, email: req.user.email};
  return app.render(req, res, "/index", msg);
});

server.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    } else if (!user) {
      req.flash("error_msg", info.message);
      return app.render(req, res, "/login", req.flash());
    } else {
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        req.user = user.name;
        return app.render(req, res, "/index", user.name);
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});

server.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logOut();
  req.flash("success_msg", "done!");
  return app.render(req, res, "/login", req.flash());
});

server.get("*", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  return handle(req, res);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you meant by `return app.render(req, res, "/index", user.name);` on your login method, is actually a `redirect`.

What render does is take the file and the data you give it and then send it back to the browser as a response.

However, what you're trying to do is have the user go to a different URL if the login process is successful, that can be accomplished by doing the following:

```
res.redirect('/index')
```

This will make the server go to your `index` route, which in turn executes all the code required for your user data to be loaded!

You can learn more about [redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) and [render](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) by looking at the express docs.